# Android ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter not calling getView()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I am extending ListFragment to display data retrieved from a web server in an AsyncTask in another class. If I set a custom height (i.e. 400dp) on the `@android:id/list` widget in my xml, getView() does not get called at all. If I set it to wrap_content, getView() gets called for the list items but the list items don't show up! It seems that the listview does not expand to fit the item heights, even though the list item's xml specifies a layout height. When a fixed height is defined I can see the colored background of the list, but no data. getCount() never returns 0.

Part of the adapter class:

```
public class gAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GroupObject> {
ArrayList<GroupObject> groups;

public gAdapter(Context context, int textViewResId, ArrayList<GroupObject> groups) {
    super(context, R.layout.groups_listview_row, groups);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    con = context;
    this.groups = groups;
} 

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos = position;
    View row = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) 
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.groups_listview_row, parent, false);
    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.groups_listview_name);
    //Set name
    try {
        name.setText( groups.get(position).groupName);
        Log.d("test", "Got name " + groups.get(position).groupName);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        name.setText("Could not load name");
    }
        return row; 
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("test", "Returning count " + (this.groups.size() != 0 ? this.groups.size() : 0));
    return this.groups.size() != 0 ? this.groups.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public GroupObject getItem(int position) {
    Log.d("test", "get item " + position);
    return this.groups.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

groups_listview_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/groups_listview_imageview"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/groups_listview_imageview"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/groups_listview_imageview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/groups_listview_imageview" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groups_listview_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groups_listview_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="zCode: 000000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groups_listview_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:text="Location" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groups_listview_numMembers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:text="0 Members" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: one thing I see is, that You are getting the LayoutInflater before initializing the context: mInflater = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    con = context;

Comment: get rid of getCount. ArrayAdapter overrides it for you. did you call setListAdapter ?

Comment: I tried both of your solutions but neither worked. And yes I have called setListAdapter; getCount() was getting called

Comment: I guess count is zero that's the reason it will not call the getview

Comment: @android_dev getCount() returns 38 every time

Comment: Why is RelativeLayout1 has a layout_height of 50dp? Try changing it to match_parent and see what happens.